# Flex - combobox data

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I'd like to create a combobox which will get users from an arrayList & another field for creating a new user.

for example when i open the combobox i'd like to see the rows :

> Create new user 
>   User A 
>   User B

where the users come form an arrayList and the "create new user" option is always there.

How can I do it?

P.S

I don't wan't to add "create new user" obj to the arryList - so this is not a desired solution.

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Just create an intermediate ArrayList, add the "create new user" option to it, copy all the elements from the other ArrayList, and finally assign it to the combobox:

```
var cbArray = new ArrayList();
cbArray.push("Create new user ");
for (int i = 0; i < yourArrayList.lenght; i++) {
    cbArray.push(yourArrayList[i]);
}
// Then assign cbArray to the combo box
```

Comment: I didn't wan't a solution like this, but I've already found the solution I wan't I just create a custom component based on the combobox and add to it the feature I want. Thanks for your time.